# Remove specific word multiple times from a string in jquery

Tags: jquery, string

So I have a string which comes from a contenteditable div, it is like this:

```
"Blah Blah Blah<div><br>Blah Blah Blah Blah </div><div><br>How are you.</div>"
```

The problem is that the  tags already create a line-break and the `<br>` just adds an extra line-break. So, is there a way to repeat a string split in order to remove all the `<br>`. Also, could it work with an x amount of `<br>`?

Essentially, I would want to get:

```
"Blah Blah Blah<div>Blah Blah Blah</div><div>How are you.</div>"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on this? What do you want your output to look like? What exactly do you want to replace?

Comment: Set the divs to `display:inline` via css?

Comment: It seems too trivial, but worth checking - have you tried `replace` ?   `var content = "Blah...etc"; var fixed = content.replace(/<br>/g, "")`;`

Comment: @RionWilliams I have added what I want the result to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Stripping Out `<br>` Elements**

You could use a regular expression to replace all of the instances of your `<br>` within the HTML of your element via the [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function :

```
$(function(){
    // Get your HTML
    var text = $('div[contenteditable]').html();
    // Perform your replacement (the 'g' flag will replace all instances)
    text = text.replace(/<br>/g,'');
    // text should now contain your content sans <br> elements
});
```

**Updating Your Content**

If you actually wanted to replace the content, you could then just set the replaced text using the [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function :

```
$(function(){
    var text = $('div[contenteditable]').html();
    // Perform your replacement
    text =text.replace(/<br>/g,'');
    $('div[contenteditable]').html(text);
});
```

**Example**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Content Replacement</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div contenteditable='true'>
    Blah Blah Blah<div><br>Blah Blah Blah Blah </div><div><br>How are you.</div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <button id='replace'>Replace and Update</button>
  <script>
    $(function(){
        // Example outputting replaced text
        console.log($('div[contenteditable]').html().replace(/<br>/g,''));
        // Actually replacing the text
        $('#replace').click(function(){
          var text = $('div[contenteditable]').html();
          // Perform your replacement
          text =text.replace(/<br>/g,'');
          $('div[contenteditable]').html(text);
        });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `.text()` to get text without HTML tags.

```
$('.your-contenteditable-div').text();
```